# Convergence of a function and interval topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a well-ordered set that contains exactly one element $x$ such that $y<x$ for uncountably many values of $y\in X$. Let $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all other values of $y\in X$. For the interval topology $\tau$ on $X$, show that for every sequence $u_n\to u$ in $X$, $f(u_n)\to f(u)$.

This is what I've tried. Let $u=x$ and $u_n\to u$. Let $B$ be a neighborhood of $f(u)=1$. It is enough to consider $B=\{1\}$. We need to show that there exists an $m$ such that $u_n=x$ for all $n\geq m$. Suppose there exists a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ such that $u_{n_k}<x$ for all $k$. Then for each $k$ there exist uncountably many $w_k$ such that $u_{n_k}< w_k<x$, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Try the other way. $[0,u_{n_k})$ is countable for all $k$ ($0$ is the smallest element of $X$, you could call it $Jim$ if you don't like $0$). So $[0,\sup u_{n_k})$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence such that $y_n<x$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $A_n=\{y\in X:y<y_n\}$. Each $A_n$ is countable, so $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ is countable, and $X\setminus A\ne\varnothing$. Let $y=\min(X\setminus A)$. Show that $y<x$, and use this to show that $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $x$.

Comment: @nokiddn: You’re welcome.